# What are those tripod-like things on the Olympic archers' bows? And what is their function?

Tags: equipment, archery

As seen on the bow in the photo of Ki Bo-bae:

[image]

(I did try searching first, but couldn't find it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're called [stabilizers](http://www.archerylearningcenter.com/blog/stabilizers) and, among other things, they help improve the accuracy and balance of the bow.